# Dynamic Model Creation and Migration in Django

Tags: sql, database, django-models, migration, django-1.9

I am working on a project where I want to create database tables (models) and migrate them to an SQL database server dynamically. What is the best way?

I know how to create a dynamic model using `migrations.createmodel` but don't know how to migrate them to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can migrate it dynamically,

```
from django.core.management import call_command
call_command('makemigrations')
call_command('migrate')
```